# Can I save images in mode_private?

Tags: java, android, url, download

Currently I save an XML file in mode_private using the following method:

```
public void Save_Data(String filename, String Datastring, Context context) {
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(Datastring.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want to save a small image roughly about 5kb from URL into my application space in mode_private. Is it possible to save images in mode_private? If so can anyone show me how I can modify the method below to do this?

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(final String DownloadUrl, final String fileName) {


    Thread web = new Thread(){
        public void run(){


       try {
               File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

               File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Chats");
               if(dir.exists()==false) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
               }

               URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
               File file = new File(dir, fileName);

               long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

               /* Open a connection to that URL. */
               URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

               /*
                * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                */
               InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
               BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

               /*
                * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                */
               ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
               int current = 0;
               while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                  baf.append((byte) current);
               }


               /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
               fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
       }

        }
        };
        web.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of Randrm I implemented the two methods below to store/retrieve a Bitmap image present in an ImageView in the app's private data space. Basically a cleaned-up version of his answer, taken from compiling code.

Might be useful if you want your Activity to quickly restore its View's contents upon resume. The ImageView is id'd by R.string.myImage, the bitmap accessed through the myBitmap member of the class.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // we will be stopped and perhaps later on destroyed;
    // store displayed image for quick retrieval in private data space
    try {
        FileOutputStream output =
           openFileOutput(this.getString(R.string.myImage), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "could not save image to private space");
    }

    // superclass to save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // superclass to restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // retrieve image stored earlier
    try {
        FileInputStream input = openFileInput(this.getString(R.string.myImage));
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.det_mainimage)).
          setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "could not retrieve image from private space");
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

So I finally figured how to save an image in mode_private

The method below takes a Bitmap and save it to your applications private space in mode_private.

```
 public String writeFileToInternalStorage(Bitmap outputImage){
        String fileName = fileName + ".png";

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
  try {
   fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);

  return fileName;
    }
```

This reads the image from the applications private space and turns it into a Bitmap :

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/"+fileName);
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.